# Creating a date and time function that updates every second

Tags: javascript, date, time

So I need this function to update every second with the current date and time. Also if minute or second is less than 10 I need to add a 0 in front. Heres my code, not sure what I'm doing wrong, I feel pretty confident in my code. Any suggestions?

```
<script>
"use strict"
// updates digital clock every second
var tick = setInterval(digitalClock, 1000);
//digital clock function
function digitalClock() {
  var currentTime();
  var dateObject = new Date();
  var hour = dateObject.getHours();
  var minute = dateObject.getMinutes();
  var second = dateObject.getSeconds();
  if (minute < 0) {
     minute = "0" + minute;
  }
  if (second < 0) {
     second = "0" + second;
  }
  currentTime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = currentTime;  
}
</script>
```

I was told that innerHTML wont work where I put it, but I dont see why not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `()` after the `currentTime` and also you need to check if `minute` and `second` is less than `10`, not `0`

```html
<p id='time'></p>

<script>
  function digitalClock() {
  var dateObject = new Date();
  var parts = {
    hours: dateObject.getHours(),
    minutes: dateObject.getMinutes(),
    seconds: dateObject.getSeconds(),
    month: dateObject.getUTCMonth() + 1,// +1 because the month starts from 0
    day: dateObject.getUTCDate(),
    year: dateObject.getUTCFullYear()
  };
 
  if (parts.minutes < 10) {
     parts.minutes = "0" + parts.minutes;
  }
  if (parts.seconds < 10) {
     parts.seconds = "0" + parts.seconds;
  }
    
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = `${parts.month}/${parts.day}/${parts.year} ${parts.hours}:${ parts.minutes}:${parts.seconds}`;  
}

var tick = setInterval(digitalClock, 1000);
  </script>
```

**UPDATED**

This is by pure `JavaScript`. But I advice you to use [**momentJs**](http://momentjs.com/) if you need to work with the times and dates many times

Comment: I also need the date to show, how do I incorporate this along with time?

Answer (score 0):

condition should be less than 10 and define var as var currentTime; instead of var currentTime();

```
<script>
 "use strict" 
// updates digital clock every second
var tick = setInterval(digitalClock, 1000);
//digital clock function
function digitalClock() {
  var currentTime;
  var dateObject = new Date();
  var hour = dateObject.getHours();
  var minute = dateObject.getMinutes();
  var second = dateObject.getSeconds();
  if (minute < 10) {
    minute = "0" + minute;
  }
  if (second < 10) {
    second = "0" + second;
  }
  currentTime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = currentTime;   
 }
 </script>
```